# How to check if path points to a root folder using Delphi

Tags: delphi

What is the best/easiest way to check if a certain path points to a drive's root?

I guess I could just check if path name ends with '\' or ':', or if the path is only 2 or three characters in length, but I was hoping there was some kind of standard "IsDriveRoot" function to check this.

Tx

UPDATE:

After searching through the Delphi help file I found the **ExtractFileDrive()** function which returns the drive portion of any given path.

Using that function I gues it's easy to write a little function to check if the original path is the same as the result of ExtractFileDrive(), which would mean that the original path had to be the drive's root.

```
Function IsDriveRoot(APath: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ((Length(APath) = 2) and (ExtractFileDrive(APath) = APath))
         or ((Length(APath) = 3) and ((ExtractFileDrive(APath) + '\') = APath));
end;
```

or

```
Function IsDriveRoot(APath: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ((Length(APath) = 2) and (Copy(APath,2,1) = ':'))
         or ((Length(APath) = 3) and (Copy(APath,3,1) = '\'));
end;
```

Something like that should do it....

I actually think the second example is simpler, and will probably end up using that one.

Thanks again to all who responded :)

Comment: Would a patch of \\SERVER\SHARE qualify if you have shared the C:\ drive root as SHARE on that SERVER?

Comment: You may also want to take into account that a removable storage device may have no letter assigned and be simply a junction point. And so something like `D:\USBDrive` may actually point to its root directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of updating the *question* with the solution you found, you should put that in an *answer* of your own. That way, people can vote on it if they think it's a good solution, and you can ultimately accept it as the "best" answer. This site works best when questions and answers are clearly separated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems [`GetVolumePathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be quite helpful in your case.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is more for checking which volume a specific path originates from. It still doesn't tell you if the given path is actually the volume's root or not. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @deonvn: You are right. But you can compare the path you are passing to this function with its result. If they are equal, then... guess what? :)

Comment: Sorry - you're right. I didn't notice that if you specify a path without a volume, the function returns just the drive letter - so yes, that will work. Found a similar solution using ExtractFileDrive(). I've updated my original post to that effect. Tx again.

Comment: @deonvn: Yes, that's a nice solution. Still you cannot address the cases of `\\SERVER\SHARE` and of junctions points with `ExtractFileDrive()`, as well as cases which my solution doesn't address either, namely `C:\Windows\..` and the likes.

Comment: If you want to deal with `C:\Windows\..` you can use [`PathCanonicalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773569%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize GetDriveType() call:

```
if GetDriveType(PChar(path)) <> DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR then
...
```

Comment: I think you meant [DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the comments on the linked page seem to imply that the method may not work for the OP.

Comment: There is no DRIVE_NOT_ROOT_DIR return for GetDriveType - it's actually DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR, which means the root path is invalid (no volume mapped at path).

Comment: Thanks. GetDriveType is handy for checking if a drive exists, and if so, what type of drive it is. However, it will not tell you if certain path relative to an existing drive points to the drive's root or not.